# The data in the sqlite database was lost after I restarted the application

Tags: python, tkinter

So here I have just added a table called create_deposits_table(), which I use to store input data from the user later, but the problem is that when I run the application, the data can be saved in the database and I check via the SQlite DB Browser that the data is there, then I close the application and I ran the application again, I checked the data that was previously in the DEPOSITS table and suddenly it disappeared, for the piece of code that I added as follows, please help me solve this problem.

my code snippet :

```
def add_data_deposit():
    try:
        # ambil data dari filed
        jumlah_setoran = v_jumlah_setoran.get()
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

        if not jumlah_setoran:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Field Jumlah setoran harus diisi")
            return
        
        if not str(jumlah_setoran).isdecimal():
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Jumlah Setoran harus berupa bilangan bulat positif")
            return
        
        if not borrow_id:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Pilih data terlebih dahulu")
            return
        
        # mendapatkan nilai POKOK dan BAGI_HASIL dari table BORROW berdasarkan ID peminjaman
        query_borrow_data = """
            SELECT POKOK, BAGI_HASIL
            FROM BORROW
            WHERE ID = :BORROW_ID
        """

        params_borrow_data = {
            "BORROW_ID" : borrow_id
        }

        cursor.execute(query_borrow_data, params_borrow_data)
        borrow_data = cursor.fetchone()

        # menghitung nilai JUMLAH_ANGSURAN berdasarkan POKOK dan BAGI_HASIL
        if borrow_data:
            pokok_value = borrow_data[0]
            bagi_hasil_value = borrow_data[1]
            jumlah_angsuran_value = pokok_value + bagi_hasil_value
        else:
            # Handle jika BORROW tidak ditemukan
            jumlah_angsuran_value = 0

        # Mendapatkan nilai selisih
        selisih_value = jumlah_angsuran_value - int(jumlah_setoran)

        # Menghitung nilai GAGAL_POTONG berdasarkan SELISIH
        gagal_potong_sebelumnya_value = get_gagal_potong_sebelumnya(borrow_id)

        # Menghitung nilai GAGAL_POTONG berdasarkan SELISIH
        gagal_potong_value = max(abs(selisih_value), 0) + gagal_potong_sebelumnya_value

        # setelah mendapatkan nilai JUMLAH_ANGSURAN, Anda dapat menggunakannya dalam query untuk megisi tabel DEPOSITS
        query_insert_deposit = """
            INSERT INTO DEPOSITS
            (JUMLAH_SETOR, JUMLAH_ANGSURAN, SELISIH, GAGAL_POTONG, TIMESTAMP, BORROW_ID)
            VALUES (:JUMLAH_SETOR, :JUMLAH_ANGSURAN, :SELISIH, :GAGAL_POTONG, :TIMESTAMP, :BORROW_ID)
        """

        params_insert_deposit = {
            "JUMLAH_SETOR" : jumlah_setoran,
            "JUMLAH_ANGSURAN" : jumlah_angsuran_value,
            "SELISIH" : selisih_value,
            "GAGAL_POTONG" : gagal_potong_value,
            "TIMESTAMP": timestamp,
            "BORROW_ID": borrow_id

        }

        cursor.execute(query_insert_deposit, params_insert_deposit)
        conn.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Data berhasil ditambahkan ! ")
        print("Data added successfully")
        update_trv_deposit()
        logging.info("Data deposit berhasil ditambahkan")
        
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Erorr during add_data_deposit: {e}")
        conn.rollback() # kembalikan perubahan jika terjadi kesalahan
        print("Error during commit : ", e)
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Gagal menyimpan perubahan ke database") 


def get_gagal_potong_sebelumnya(borrow_id):
    try:
        query = """
            SELECT GAGAL_POTONG
            FROM DEPOSITS
            WHERE BORROW_ID = :BORROW_ID
            ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
            LIMIT 1
        """
        params = {
            "BORROW_ID": borrow_id
        }
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result:
            return result[0]  # Mengembalikan nilai GAGAL_POsONG terakhir
        else:
            return 0  # Jika tidak ada data DEPOSITS terkait, mengembalikan 0

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in get_gagal_potong_sebelumnya:", e)
        return 0  # Mengembalikan 0 jika terjadi kesalahan
```

I hope the data I have added to the DEPOSITS table is not lost when my application is restarted

Comment: I don't see where in your code you're opening the sqlite database.

Comment: I uses this code for open my database

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

Comment: It is better a provide a [mre] instead of just two functions.